# A rectangle is drawn so that it fits inside the region bound by the curve $y=4Sin(x)$

Tags: geometry, derivatives, optimization

A rectangle is drawn so that it fits inside the region bound by the curve $y=4Sin(x)$ where $0 \le x \le \pi$ and the x-axis. Find the maximum perimeter of the rectangle using optimization.

So far i've tried to say since it's a rectangle $P=2x+2y$ and thus, $P=2x+8Sin(x)$. But finding the maximum value of $x$ by letting the derivative be $0$ ended up with the value of $x$ being $104.47$. Which is outside the domain given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Update: My calculator was in degrees not radians.

Comment: To construct the rectangle we will need to choose two $x$ points, some $x$ and $x_1$. The two $x$ values will be related by $x = \pi -x_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by $x$ and $y$ in your answer. The variables should be clearly defined.

Here's one way to approach this: first establish that any such rectangle will: a) touch the curve at two vertices and b) be symmetrical about the vertical line $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Both of these are easy to show by elementary arguments.

Once you've done that, define $2X$ to be the length horizontal base of the rectangle, i.e. the base which spans from $\frac{\pi}{2}-X$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}+X$. The vertical height is $4\sin({\frac{\pi}{2}+X}) = 4\cos X$. The perimeter (twice the length of the base plus twice the height) is therefore $4X + 8\cos X = 4(X + 2\cos X)$.

This is the quantity you have to maximise. So set $f(X) = 4(X + 2\cos X)$ and compute $f'(X)$ then set $f'(X) = 0$. Show that it is a maximum by considering the sign of $f''(X)$. Finally, use this to find the perimeter. The rest should be quite easy, just basic calculus.

Comment: Ok i understand, however why is it $4X+8CosX$? Shouldn't it be $2X+8CosX$?

Comment: The $4X$ doesn't quite make sense

Comment: @Brayden Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. The perimeter is twice the length plus twice the height. In this case, the length of the base is $2X$, so twice that is $4X$. The height is $4\cos X$, so twice that is $8\cos X$. Add those up.

Comment: @Brayden I also corrected a small typo. To show it is maximal you need to consider the *sign* of $f''(X)$ (the second derivative (not equate it to zero). I also wrote "minimum" when I meant "maximum" (of course), and this has also been corrected.

Comment: Oh ok i see, but i don't see how the horizontal length is $2X$? I just had it as $X$ in mine.

Comment: @Brayden Note how I defined my rectangle's base. I first established the vertical midline to be the vertical line through $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ - this is the symmetry of the figure. I let $X$ be the distance of each base vertex from this point. So the base spans from the $x$- coordinates $\frac{\pi}{2}-X$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}+X$. The length is the difference between those $x$-coordinates, which is $2X$. Is that clearer? There are many ways to formulate a problem, and you might find another formulation easier to work with. All you have to do is ensure consistency and properly define all your terms. :)

Comment: I see now, thankyou for your help

Comment: @Brayden No worries, glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused with the concept of radian and degree systems.

$104.47$ degree is basically ${104.47\over\ 180}\pi$ in radian and your answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah i realized my calculator was still in degrees but i have an answer now for it after resolving the issue. Thanks